# VBA: using split function to compare multiple strings to 1 other string

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make an equation with the split function in VBA.
The string that needs to be split comes from a excel sheet and looks in the cell like this: **text1;tex2;text3**

I load this in a variable so I get the following:

```
string1 = "text1;text2;text3"
string2 = "text2"
```

Now what I want to do is the following

```
If string2 = Split(string1, ";", , CompareMethod.Text) Then
    'Do something
End If
```

But this approuch seems to throw an error.
 It's the first time I use the split function however so I"m guessing I'm using it all wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to isolate each of the elements that are returned from the `Split` function. The `Split` function converts a string to an array of string.

An array is iterable with a `For...Each` structure, so you could do like this:

```
Dim string1 as String
Dim string2 as String
Dim arrString as Variant
Dim str as Variant

string1 = "text1;text2;text3"

string2 = "text2"

For each str in Split(string1, ";", , CompareMethod.Text)
    If str = string2 Then
        'Do something
    End If
Next
```

Comment: it worked but only after deleting the CompareMethod.Text, I don't know why but it trew me some general error. If I just deleted CompareMethod.Text, no change to the rest it worked

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but you can wrap each string with the delimiter and do it in a single line, like this:

```
If InStr(1, ";" & string1 & ";", ";" & string2 & ";", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    'do something
End If
```

As a side note, this is faster than splitting and looping (especially if there are a lot of members to search). The string allocations in the split and the loop are expensive compared to the two allocations used in appending the delimiters, and then the very fast InStr function. Even faster if you don't use vbTextCompare.

- Fast
- Concise
- Ugly

Choose your delimiter wisely. I like `•` (Alt+0149) because it's easy to see and VERY uncommon as a text entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
If Not IsError(Application.Match(string2, Split(string1, ";"), 0)) Then
    '~~> Do some cool stuff
End If
```

Use this if you are trying to only check presence of `string2` in `string1`.
Actually, same effect with what Lima posted.
If you want to do something for every occurrence, then use David's route. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Filter` to return an array of matches against the `Split` source string (without looping through the `Split` string)

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim vArr
str1 = "text1;text2;text3"
str2 = "text2"
vArr = Filter(Split(str1, ";"), str2, True, vbBinaryCompare)
If Len(Join(vArr, ",")) > 0 Then MsgBox "do something"
```